# Why the CSS style "visibility:visible" appears in my nodelist only when I enter it directly in my HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here my sandbox: https://codepen.io/joondoe/pen/OeQBEb

**My problem**: I'm wondering why the CSS property `visibility:visible` disappears from the nodelist when I remove it from the HTML markup.

**info**: *the nodelist is called on the console when we push the button display_node_list. The nodelist of the first button wll be displayed directly at the `visibility:style`'s entry. If you remove the inline style in the HTML markup the metadata "visible" will disappear. I'm wondering why this phenomenon occurs.*

Here my snippet:

```js
function toggleFontName(){ 
  let fontNameStock= Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("i")) 
  console.log("typeof fontNameStock[0].style.visibility: ", fontNameStock[0].style.visibility) 
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface|Amatic+SC|Caveat|Cormorant+Garamond|Courgette|EB+Garamond|Faster+One|Glass+Antiqua|Gloria+Hallelujah|Inconsolata|Inknut+Antiqua|Megrim|Patua+One|Permanent+Marker|Raleway+Dots|Rationale|Roboto|Roboto+Condensed|Russo+One|Rye|Satisfy|Shadows+Into+Light|Sue+Ellen+Francisco|Unna|Vast+Shadow&display=swap');

button{
  font-size: 12px; 
  position:fixed;
  left: 15px;
  top:40%;
}

button:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
}

i{
  visibility:visible;
} 

h2{
  padding:0;
  margin-bottom:1em;
}
.content{
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
  margin-bottom:10vh;
}

hr{
  color:rgb(186, 186, 186);
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.Cormorant_Garamond{
  font-family:"Cormorant Garamond";
}

.EB_Garamond{
  font-family:"EB Garamond"
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleFontName()">display_node_list</button>
<div class="content Cormorant_Garamond" >
  <i style="visibility:visible">Cormorant Garamond</i><br/>
  <br/>
   <h2> <b>Design for the audience</b> </h2>
</div>

<hr size="1px" width="35%" noshade>

<div class="content EB_Garamond" >
   <i>EB Garamond</i><br/>
  <br/>
   <h2> <b>Design for the audience</b> </h2>
</div>

<hr size="1px" width="35%" noshade>
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding. `.style.visibility` looks in the inline `style="..."` for a `visibility` property. If you then *removed* that property, why would it still be in the nodelist? I don't mean that rhetorically, I'm just trying to get an idea of the reasons behind your expectation so I can provide a bit more clarity.

Comment: Cascaded Style Sheets and element's inline style objects are totally different objects, setting or removing a property to / from other object doesn't have an effect to another object.

Comment: @Santi thanks for your feedback, I thought the fact to set it in the CSS would makes it available in the nodelist, the others have well answered to this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)** is is used to get (as well as set) the **inline** `style` of an element.

In the above, this is set with `<i style="visibility:visible">`.

> When getting, it returns a [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) object that contains a list of all styles properties for that element with values assigned for the attributes that are defined in the element's inline [`style` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style).

If you remove the inline style, JavaScript will be unable to access it.
Note that this is also the case even if the property is set in `<head>` or an *external* stylesheet:

> The style property is not useful for completely learning about the styles applied on the element, since it represents only the CSS declarations set in the element's inline style attribute, not those that come from `style` rules elsewhere, such as style rules in the `<head>` section, or external style sheets.

This means that if you set:

```
i {
  visibility:visible;
}
```

`HTMLElement.style` will not be able to find it.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
function toggleFontName(){ 
  let fontNameStock= Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("i")) 
  console.log("typeof fontNameStock[0].style.visibility: ", fontNameStock[0].style.visibility) 
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface|Amatic+SC|Caveat|Cormorant+Garamond|Courgette|EB+Garamond|Faster+One|Glass+Antiqua|Gloria+Hallelujah|Inconsolata|Inknut+Antiqua|Megrim|Patua+One|Permanent+Marker|Raleway+Dots|Rationale|Roboto|Roboto+Condensed|Russo+One|Rye|Satisfy|Shadows+Into+Light|Sue+Ellen+Francisco|Unna|Vast+Shadow&display=swap');

button{
  font-size: 12px; 
  position:fixed;
  left: 15px;
  top:40%;
}

button:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
}

i{
  visibility:visible;
} 

h2{
  padding:0;
  margin-bottom:1em;
}
.content{
  width:50%;
  margin:auto;
  margin-bottom:10vh;
}

hr{
  color:rgb(186, 186, 186);
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.Cormorant_Garamond{
  font-family:"Cormorant Garamond";
}

.EB_Garamond{
  font-family:"EB Garamond"
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleFontName()">display_node_list</button>
<div class="content Cormorant_Garamond" >
  <i>Cormorant Garamond</i><br/>
  <br/>
   <h2> <b>Design for the audience</b> </h2>
</div>

<hr size="1px" width="35%" noshade>

<div class="content EB_Garamond" >
   <i>EB Garamond</i><br/>
  <br/>
   <h2> <b>Design for the audience</b> </h2>
</div>

<hr size="1px" width="35%" noshade>
```